# Service to browse all contrib modules on drupal.org

Tags: 7

http://simplytest.me/ allows you to search all existing modules. I'm trying to implement a widget with the same functionality, but I'm stuck on how to browse all the projects on drupal.org... Can someone point me in the right direction? I found the module "project_browser", but can't seem to figure out how they accomplish it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This excellent script [written by rocketeerbkw](https://github.com/rocketeerbkw/drupal_function_stats/blob/master/get_list_of_modules.php) will create a text file containing the name of every d.o contrib module, giving you everything you need to get started:

```
/**
 * Download a full list of all modules on drupal.org by using the API. More info
 * at https://www.drupal.org/about-drupalorg/api.
 */
$url = 'https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node.json?type=project_module';
$modules = array();
do {
  print $url . PHP_EOL;
  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'user_agent' => 'get_list_of_modules.php from https://github.com/rocketeerbkw/drupal_function_stats',
      'header' => 'Accept: application/json',
    ),
  );
  $context = stream_context_create($options);
  $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  $data = json_decode($response);
  foreach ($data->list as $module) {
    $modules[] = $module->field_project_machine_name;
  }
  $url = isset($data->next) ? $data->next : FALSE;
  // The next links are always provided without a format [#2253947].
  // Formatless URLs are 301 redirected to format URLs but strip all query
  // query parameters [#2364755].
  $url = str_replace('node?', 'node.json?', $url);
} while ($url);
$file = fopen('project_usage.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, implode("\n", $modules));
fclose($file);
```

An example output is here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocketeerbkw/drupal_function_stats/master/project_usage.txt

Once you've got that data the only tasks are deciding where/how to store it, and creating the UI to manage it.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed! To the point... instead of people whining that I'm asking for a big chunk of code or a book...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Project Browser Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_browser_server) module. Please read the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1612058).

> This module provides an API as well as endpoints so that you can serve
>   search results to the Module / Theme Browser module.